# Oracle Select distinct group by rowid

Tags: oracle, group-by, distinct, rowid

I have a db table like this:

```
citizen-gender-age-personid
uk      female-35 -1
uk      male  -35 -1
de      male  -24 -2
gr      female 15 -3
        female 15 -3
ab      male   20 -4 
        male   20 -4
ab      female 21 -5
```

so a `personid` have multi age or gender or citizen or all `nullable` maybe. I must write a sql and results must be only one record of all `personid.like` that:

```
uk      female-35 -1
de      male  -24 -2
gr      female 15 -3
ab      male   20 -4
ab      female 21 -5
```

Comment: Do you have any rule to decide what data are the good data for a personid ? Or do you want to keep all lines, and just assume they all relates to distinct persons (i.e the personid is just completely useless) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT personid
      ,MAX(age) AS age
      ,MAX(gender) AS gender
      ,MAX(citizen) AS citizen
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY personid;
```

Comment: excuse me.i have 2.3 bilion recors.so i must get count of personid group ny age,gender,citizen.

Comment: @mrcomp Excused!!! regardless of how many records you have, you will need to run this query to get what you want, also I don't understand your comment about the count??? You have not mentioned anything about the count in your question.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution :

```
  SELECT t.citizen, t.gender, t.age,count(distinct(personid)) FROM table1 t
```

where
      rowid= (SELECT
                   MAX ( ROWID )
             FROM
                   table1 B
             WHERE
                   t.personid = B.personid)                    group by t.citizen, t.gender, t.age

Comment: But what was the question ?